GraphJS mouse hover timezone
I'm working on building a status page for all of my microservices using graphjs (page available here), and when hovering over points of data the timezone is UTC, but I was hoping there's a way to set it automatically based on the user's timezone.
My config for the graphs is
          <script>
              new Chart(document.getElementById('chart-${index}'), {
                  type: 'line',
                  data: {
                      labels: ${JSON.stringify(labels)},
                      datasets: [{
                          label: 'Response Time',
                          data: ${JSON.stringify(datapoints)},
                          fill: true,
                          borderColor: '#43b581',
                          cubicInterpolationMode: 'monotone',
                          tension: 0.2,
                          pointBorderWidth: 0
                      }]
                  },
                  options: {
                      responsive: true,
                      maintainAspectRatio: false,
                      scales: {
                          x: {
                              display: false
                          },
                          y: {
                              beginAtZero: true
                          }
                      },
                      plugins: {
                          legend: {
                              display: false
                          }
                      }
                  }
              });
          </script>



Where is the code that provides your time on hover?
